# How does [UIAlertView show] work?

Tags: objective-c, uialertview

I want to do something similar to UIAlertView, ie - without reference to any UIView or UIViewController, present a UIViewController on top of all windows using presentModalViewController.

Looking at the documentation I can't find a way in which this is possible!

In OS4, there is something like this:

```
UIWindow *window = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow
UIViewController *rootViewController = window.rootViewController
```

...but this is not possible in OS3.

Does anyone know how to achieve the same effect in OS3?

Thanks!

---

OK - so I solved this with a myriad of delegate callbacks to the ViewController itself! Although it's the proper way to achieve this, it did seem kind-of odd that's it's not possible at any stage in execution get a handle to the top View Controller for alerts (etc).

If anyone knows how to achieve this, I'd be still really interested!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`UIAlertView` creates its own `UIWindow` above your application's main window, `makeKeyAndVisible`-s it, and animates in its own views in that window.

Comment: Ahh - eye opening! Thank you for this! Nick

Comment: What/who retains the UIWindow instance? When I create an instance of UIWindow but do not retain it as an instance variable/property it never appears and also seems to be dropped from the `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows]` array. Am I missing something?

Comment: Ok so in an attempt to create an overlay that acts similar to UIAlertView, I made my UIWindow subclass effectively retain itself by creating a retain cycle. I am assigning `self` to a strong property, then in my dismiss method I set that property to nil. Seems to work, is this a bad idea? I am assuming UIAlertView does something similar.

Comment: @ChrisWagner Bad idea. Internally, there is a `_UIAlertManager` which handles these issues. When you call `show` and `hide`, it takes charge and creates the windows, retains them and is responsible for releasing them.

Comment: Who retains the `_UIAlertManager`? Is it a singleton?