# Get a reference to the currently visible view controller

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I have a `UIAlertView`. When the user taps a button in the alert view I want to show a new `UIViewController`.

In order to achieve this I need to know which view controller is currently visible on screen because that particular view controller is the right one to present the new view controller.

The problem is that I have a complex hierarchy of view controllers in my app including a `UINavigationController` and a `UITabBarController` (among others). So I cannot simply use `self.visibleViewController` to get the currently visible view controller.

I have found a [possible solution on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12684721/2062785) but I would like to find a neater solution without having to dig through the whole view controller stack.

Comment: I'm not sure if this works or not, I haven't tested it but if you're creating a UIAlertView and presenting it within the last visible UIViewController, doesn't that mean the "delegate" of that UIAlertView is your last visible view controller?

Comment: I am a bit confused. You must have set the code for UIAlertView somewhere. On which ViewController you have set that?

Comment: The delegate of a `UIAlertView` is not necessarily a `UIViewController`. It can be any class that conforms to the `UIAlertViewDelegate` protocol. In my case the delegate is actually a `UIViewController` but it is a specific one that is not always visible.

Comment: @Puneet: A `UIAlertView` is not necessarily presented by a specific `UIViewController`. Instead, I use `[alertView show]`. I can call that method from anywhere in my code because a [UIAlertView always creates its own window](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3727470/2062785).

Answer (score 5):

`UINavigationController` has a property called `topViewController`. 
Maybe it helps you.

Comment: I need a solution that is not dependent on the type of the view controller.